# Highlighting Variable Occurrence in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

how can we Highlight variable wherever used in source code in languages like C++.

Comment: You might want to clarify your question. Can you give an example of what it looks like now, and what you'd prefer it to look like? (when i saw the title, I at first thought you meant "select all", but I think you are looking for "syntax highlighting".)

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a tmLanguage file:
[Syntax Definitions](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/syntaxdefs.html)